# Sublime text autocompletion for Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, sublimetext3, laravel-blade, autosuggest

Are there any plugins available to get Laravel auto completion and Laravel Blade template beautification in Sublime Text 3?
I have googled it, didn't find the right one for Laravel auto complete and not even one plugin that beautify the Laravel blade template.

Comment: i used phpstorm and its best btw

Comment: any idea for sublime_text ide?

Comment: no, but if phpstorm is pretty best at auto suggestion in case of laravel.

Comment: The problem with phpStorm is that it gets slow over time, I am using the best iMac 5K desktop - after a while, working on large files, i will wait 200ms between keystrokes to see my text appearing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is [dev4dev/blade-snippets](https://github.com/dev4dev/blade-snippets). You can install it via Package Manager:

[image]

After installing you will be able to autocomplete Blade snippets by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Some examples:

[image]

[image]

List of all snippets you can find in the project's repo: https://github.com/dev4dev/blade-snippets/tree/master/snippets

Answer (score 8):

First install [Sublime Code Intel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel) plugin and then install [Laravel Ide Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper).

By default Sublime Code Intel will let you autocomplete the code you write in your project e.g. extra classes, laravel's namespaces, etc but by default it will not autocomplete laravel's facades that's why Laravel Ide Helper comes to the rescure.